# Can anyone help me understand this logic please?

Tags: javascript

```
var array1 = new Array(3,5,2,7,6);
var array2 = new Array(5);
var i;
for(i=0; i<array1.length; i++) {
 array2[array2.length-i-1] = array1[i%3+1];
}
document.writeln(array2);
```

the output is as follows: 2,5,7,2,5
I'm a bit confused on this, any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Nope. Take a piece of paper and debug it.

Comment: What is the problem? Is your confusion about the array which turns out to have more elements all of a sudden? The operator precedence of the `%` and `+` operators? The `document.write` that was deprecated years ago, but still appears to work?

Comment: I'm failing to understand how it outputs 2,5,7,2,5. I'm trying to follow the logic of the argument but, i must be missing something.

Comment: Well, there is only one thing to understand here. `array2.length-i-1` returns the index in the descending order and `i % 3 + 1` == `(i % 3) + 1` will always  give a number in the range 1-3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy to debug stuff... Just display more data along the way so you can see what stuff is

Click <kbd>Run code snippet...</kbd> to see it run

```js
document.write("<pre>");
var array1 = new Array(3,5,2,7,6);
var array2 = new Array(5);
var i;
for(i=0; i<array1.length; i++) {
  document.writeln("array2[" + array2.length + "-" + i + "-" + "1] = array1[" + i + "%" + "3+1];");
  document.writeln("array2[" + (array2.length-i-1) + "] = array1[" + (i%3+1) + "];");
  document.writeln(array2);
  document.writeln();
  array2[array2.length-i-1] = array1[i%3+1];
}
document.writeln("final");
document.writeln(array2);
```

Comment: Thanks, I think i've got the jist of it!